# Screen issue when using vim

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, display

When I launch vim in a window of gnu screen, it shows the file as if I had inserted two 'z's at the initial cursor position, but the file is in fact correct and these 'z's just get over written the next time something happens in those positions (even just moving the cursor over them), and subsequent characters get set back to what they would be if they were not offset once there is activity in their positions. Also, if I ctrl+L the screen to refresh it everything goes right. In addition, sometimes screen boundaries are overwritten (the white lines between windows overwritten with the default black background, until refreshing the display sets it right again).

The issue happens both in virtual consoles and in terminal emulators within the gui.

I am on a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 22.04 on a 2014 Macbook Pro.

I just can't figure out where to start looking into an issue like this, so even a pointer in the right direction would be very helpful.